# use angular variable in tag html

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, html

this is my controller.js code:

```
$scope.animatt = 900;
```

and this is my html code:

```
<div id="properties" data-{{animatt}}="left:100%;top:10%;">
                <h2>all numeric properties</h2>
</div>
```

I want to set 'data-900=' with 'data-{{animatt}}', but this code not work

Comment: are you sure the controlle ris binded correctly? .. does it work if you simply put <p>{{animatt}}</p> in your html? ..can you see 900?

Comment: yes, I see 900 when use in tag p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, add the following code,

```
var el =angular.element('#properties');
el.attr('data-' + $scope.animatt, 'left:100%;top:10%;');
```